# Unable to find dll in a c# mobile application after cab's installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, mobile, dll, cab

I am not practice with Mobile application and i am having some issue with the deployment.

I wrote a Form application in c# that should run in a mobile computer ( i guess it doesn't matter but it's a Dolphin 6100)... let's say 'myApp'.
I included in a visual studio'solution the 'myApp' project and after that i added a cab's project following step by step this tutorial and everything seems to work  --> http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html

But after i put the cab installer in my mobile device and install the application with a re-boot, i don't know how, when i click the myApp.exe always i got this error:
"File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089', or one of its dependencies was not found"

...even if the dll is correctly in the folder!

I really don't know where i am doing wrong...!
Thank's to all.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
Just a bit of inexperience; you can't do a mobile application with a Form application using Visual Studio... you have to use a Device application instead.

Everything just works fine now.